Venting Bathroom Through Roof
Moved into a recently renovated home. Bathroom is currently vented into attic, no duct is even attached to the fan. My roof has several vents with nothing attached to them, I'm assuming to let the attic breathe. Would there be any issues with me running ducting to one of these for venting the bathroom fan? Pictures below of the roof vents and what one of them look like from the attic.
https://imgur.com/a/VFCHcRc

My hesitation would be: what happens if heavy rainstorm with strong wind pushes some water back through that vent? A small amount of water in an attic is mostly harmless. A small amount of water in an electrically powered fan may not be. Installing the duct with a "drip loop"  which has a small drain hole might be sufficient to guard against that, but I'd ask somebody who knows your climate.

It would certainly be an improvement over the current state of affairs.
Whether the reduced roof ventilation this change brings would be problematic itself is hard to say.  Building standards often exceed what is strictly necessary.
